# Alinhar button dentro de alert

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

To precisando deixa um button alinhando dentro do elemento "alert" do boostrap. 
Tentei fazer isso com a classe "pull-right", porém metade do button fica fora do elemento.

Alguem consegue me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" integrity="sha256-0XAFLBbK7DgQ8t7mRWU5BF2OMm9tjtfH945Z7TTeNIo=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.js" integrity="sha256-29KjXnLtx9a95INIGpEvHDiqV/qydH2bBx0xcznuA6I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
    <form action="/Ti01/AprovaSolicitacao" method="post">
        <h4>Esta solicitação ainda está pendente de sua aprovação!</h4>
        <input htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, readonly = readonly }" id="CadastroID" name="CadastroID" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-finish pull-right" name="aprova" value="Aprovar" onclick="$('#ModalAprovar').modal('show');">
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAprovar" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title text-left">Aprovação da Solicitação</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Digite uma justificativa
                        <textarea class="form-control" cols="4" id="ObservacaoAprov" name="ObservacaoAprov" rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Concluir</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara use o Grid do Bootstrap, use `row>col` etc, no caso se precisar use `offset` nas `col` para gerar "espaços vazios" entre uma coluna e outra. No caso eu até removi a classe `pull-right` que na verdade está colocando `float:right` no seu `btn`. Sugiro que vc pare uma horinha para ler a documentação do Grid!  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima. Essa opção não usa CSS extra, apenas o grid e classes do BS. Se quiser customizar o CSS é possível tb...

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" integrity="sha256-0XAFLBbK7DgQ8t7mRWU5BF2OMm9tjtfH945Z7TTeNIo=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.js" integrity="sha256-29KjXnLtx9a95INIGpEvHDiqV/qydH2bBx0xcznuA6I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
    <form action="/Ti01/AprovaSolicitacao" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7 text-center">
                <h4 class="">Esta solicitação ainda está pendente de sua aprovação!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3 text-center text-sm-right">
                <input htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, readonly = readonly }" id="CadastroID" name="CadastroID" type="hidden" value="1">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-finish " name="aprova" value="Aprovar" onclick="$('#ModalAprovar').modal('show');">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAprovar" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title text-left">Aprovação da Solicitação</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Digite uma justificativa
                        <textarea class="form-control" cols="4" id="ObservacaoAprov" name="ObservacaoAprov" rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Concluir</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloque o botão dentro de uma div com a classe `.text-right`. Essa classe aplica a propriedade `text-align: right`. Por ser inline, o botão será alinhado à direita:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" integrity="sha256-0XAFLBbK7DgQ8t7mRWU5BF2OMm9tjtfH945Z7TTeNIo=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.js" integrity="sha256-29KjXnLtx9a95INIGpEvHDiqV/qydH2bBx0xcznuA6I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
    <form action="/Ti01/AprovaSolicitacao" method="post" class="d-flex">
        <h4>Esta solicitação ainda está pendente de sua aprovação!</h4>
        <input htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, readonly = readonly }" id="CadastroID" name="CadastroID" type="hidden" value="1">
        <div class="text-right">
           <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-finish" name="aprova" value="Aprovar" onclick="$('#ModalAprovar').modal('show');">
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAprovar" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title text-left">Aprovação da Solicitação</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Digite uma justificativa
                        <textarea class="form-control" cols="4" id="ObservacaoAprov" name="ObservacaoAprov" rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Concluir</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```